# "ValueError: NumExpr 2 does not support Unicode as a dtype." when combining elements of rows of a datamframe in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

That's the whole code:

```
   states = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    for key in Zeitreihen_2.keys():
        conditions = [
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.1),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.1) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.2),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.2) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.3),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.3) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.4),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.4) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.5),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.5) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.6),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.6) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.7),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.7) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.8),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.8) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=0.9),
            (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]>0.9) & (Zeitreihen_2[key]["values"]<=1.01), 
            ]
        #print(Zeitreihen_2[key].head(3))
        Zeitreihen_2[key]["state"] = np.select(conditions, states)
        Zeitreihen_2[key]["transition"]= 0 
        Zeitreihen_2[key]["start"]= 0 
        Zeitreihen_2[key]["to"]= 0 
    
        Zeitreihen_2[key]["start"] = Zeitreihen_2[key]["state"]
        Zeitreihen_2[key]["to"] = Zeitreihen_2[key]["state"].shift(-1)
        Zeitreihen_2[key] = Zeitreihen_2[key].dropna()
    
        Zeitreihen_2[key]["transition"] = Zeitreihen_2[key]["state"]+ " to " +Zeitreihen_2[key]["to"]
```

The error only appears on the last row.

I was not sure if the operation is allowed but I would not have expected this kind of error.

Comment: `Zeitreihen_2[key] = Zeitreihen_2[key].dropna`... `dropna` is a function, you need to call it.

Comment: @PaulM. thanks, totally missed that. However now I get this error, on the same line:
ValueError: NumExpr 2 does not support Unicode as a dtype.

Answer (score 1):

`Zeitreihen_2[key]["transition"] = Zeitreihen_2[key]["state"]+ " to " +Zeitreihen_2[key]["to"]`

In the above line, the `Zeitreihen_2[key]["state"]` is either `int`/`float` and similarly `Zeitreihen_2[key]["to"]` is `int`.

The error is thrown as you are trying to concatenate a `int` with a string (" to ").

Try converting the `int` to `str` before concatenation:

`Zeitreihen_2[key]["transition"] = Zeitreihen_2[key]["state"].astype(str) + " to " + Zeitreihen_2[key]["to"].astype(str)`

or

`Zeitreihen_2[key]["transition"] = str(Zeitreihen_2[key]["state"]) + " to " + str(Zeitreihen_2[key]["to"])`